# How long does an old FCM token stay valid for after a new FCM one is issued?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't seem to find doucmentation on the exact period of time on when an old FCM token becomes invalid after a new FCM token is issued to the same device. Any insights would be appriciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community I am looking for documentation/clarification on the time period where a FCM token stays valid for after a new token is issued through getToken. The scenario is app has a FCM token (old token), then app gets a new token manually through getToken call (new token); how long does the old token stay as a valid token in the perspective of Firebase?